# How To Capture Proxy Error (HTML page returned) In C#

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm writing a small program in C# to parse a list of URLs. The main goal is to determine what can get through the proxy and what cannot. I believe I have accomplished this. Now I'm trying to determine why a website is blocked by the proxy. Eventually this data will be exported to a .csv for a report. I'm leaving a few details out about why I'm doing this in order to be concise.

I'm using WebClient to test each site. If the proxy refuses the connection, my program fails with an exception of:

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I can easily capture the exception and record this. However, the HTML page that the proxy returns (if I'm using a web browser) has a lot of information I would like to capture (e.g., The reputation of the site, the category that was blocked, etc.). I would like to capture this as a string and parse it with a regex. I'm stuck trying to get this HTML into a string.

To paraphrase, for a URL that is not blocked, I can easily capture the HTML of that page to a string and parse it. However, for a URL that is blocked, my program throws an exception. I have browsed the exception, and I cannot find the HTML that the proxy would normally return to a web browser in the event of a block.

Below is a bit of my code. I'm just getting started, and this has a bit to go before it is complete, lol. Thanks!

```
        int counter = 0;
        string line; //Store each line of a text file (a URL)
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        // Read the file line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(txtPath.Text); //path to file with list of URLs
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line); //for testing
            counter++;                
            string downloadString = client.DownloadString(line);
            Console.WriteLine(downloadString); //for testing
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial-n-error and trolling around, I think I have this.

Of course, with any exception we want to catch there needs to be a try/catch block around the relevant code. In this case:

```
string downloadString = client.DownloadString(line);
```

Once I catch the error as a "WebException ex", I can parse through the response stream:

```
string resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(resp);
```

At this point, I need to manipulate the HTML as a String to meet my needs. In any case, the key was to catch the error as a WebException and parse the response stream.